# Connectivity Internet - how can I try to connect for 5 secs and then give up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability, connectivity

I would like to connect to the Internet.  If after 5 secs I haven't connected (using Reachability) I want to abort.  Is this possible ?

Comment: If your question is about a specific language or framework, it's extremely helpful if you add a tag for that language or framework to your question when posting. It helps get it in front of the people that are interested in questions about that topic, which gets you an answer more quickly. It also helps future users searching for a solution for their problem.

Comment: It looks from Googling like you mean a tool for iOS or OS X framework--but the question and tags should say so, so iOS/OS X people see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSTimer with a callback for 1 second and a counter. If 5 attempts fail, 5 seconds has passed.

Something like:

```
var timerCounter = 0
var timer : NSTimer?

func shouldAttemptConnection() {
  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "attemptConnection", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  self.attemptConnection()
}

func attemptConnection() {
  if Reachability.isReachable() {
     // Handle success code

  } else if ++timerCounter >= 5 {
     // Handle timeout code

  } else {
     // Try again
     return
  }

  self.invalidateTimer()
}

func invalidateTimer() {
  timer?.invalidate()
  timer = nil
  timerCounter = 0
}
```